# Pandas read csv with stride

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series CSV file which looks like this:

```
Date    |  Number of people
============================
01/01   |  2
02/01   |  4
03/01   |  1
04/01   |  5
05/01   |  3
```

I would like to parse this file into a data frame using pandas (or some other way) so I get something like this (this is what I'm looking to get):

```
Date    |  Number of people
==============================
01/01   |  2
02/01   |  4

02/01   |  4
03/01   |  1

03/01   |  1
04/01   |  5

04/01   |  5
05/01   |  3
```

I've added spaces to make it easier to read, but its basically creating blocks of the time series and then moving half one a block (2 rows) at every row.

How would I do this with Pandas?

Comment: Better would be to keep the dataframe the same length, but have one column offset, no? You can use `.shift()` to shift a column by one row, so that you can compare the current to previous value. You can definitely zip those together to get this same format you asked for, but I'm curious what the use-case is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, using `pandas.concat`:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df.iloc[i:i+2] for i in range(df.shape[0]-1)])
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
    Date  Numberofpeople
0  01/01               2
1  02/01               4
1  02/01               4
2  03/01               1
2  03/01               1
3  04/01               5
3  04/01               5
4  05/01               3
```